# Optimization problem involving the sum of reciprocals of variables

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, relaxations

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem involving reciprocals.

The problem has the following simple form. Can this form be transformed into a problem form that commercial optimization solvers can solve (eg LP, QP ..)?

$$\begin{split}
&\text{min } x+y+z\\
&\text{s.t.}\\
&\frac1x + \frac1y +\frac1z \geq 1\\
&x,y,z \geq 1
\end{split}$$

The answer would be 3, however, what I want to ask is how to re-formulate it when there is reciprocal constraints in a problem where the objective function and other constraints are linear combinations.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be a good idea to give us some context on why you care about the problem, or where you found it. I don't think it's fully necessary in this exact case, but it might prevent downvotes from those who do.

Comment: There is no minimum.  The infimum is $0$, approached by taking $x,y,z$ all close to $0$. Or did you mean $\le 1$?

Comment: The solution is that x, y,, z have to be as close as possible to 0, but not  0. What ever value you choose there exists a smaller value. Thus there is no optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.

Rotert, as you said there is no minimum to the original question, thus I fixed the problem.

However, what I want to ask was how to re-formulate it when there is one reciprocal constraint in a problem where the objective function and other constraints are linear combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make piecewise linearization of each of the fraction (reciprocals) using Taylor series. This technique will not be accurate and the bounds may not be tight. In solver problems usually its like

Min $ x+y+z$
s.t.
(1) $ x_1+y_1+z_1  \ge 1$
(2) $ x_1 \cdot x - 1 = 0$
(3) $ y_1 \cdot y - 1 = 0$
(4) $ z_1 \cdot z - 1 = 0$
$ 0 \le x_1,y_1, z_1 \le 1$

Most solvers wont have a problem with constraints (2)-(4)

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention Taylor series here -- I don't think this is a linearization. This is creating slack variables based on the exact algebraic relationship between x and 1/x. Overall, I think this is a good approach. Constraints of the form $xy=1$ are common in optimization. I've seen a few methods that rely on relaxing $xy=0$ into $xy=k$.

Comment: Thank you Alek. The solution you mentioned can be formulated as a QCP (Quadratic constrained problem) using the term xy=1? If so, can you give me an example finding the solution of an optimization problem involving xy=1?

Answer (score 0):

With the substitutions $a = 1/x, b = 1/y, c = 1/z$, it is equivalent to the following **convex** problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{a, b, c} \quad \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad a + b + c \ge 1; \\
 &\qquad\,\, a, b, c > 0; \quad a, b, c \le 1.
\end{align*}

CVX can solve it.